# Selenium with Jenkins on MAC

Tags: macos, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Can someone explain step by step procedure to execute Selenium with Jenkins on ***MAC***? There are many Video for windows but nothing on ***MAC***.

Steps required:

1. How to set Classpath in terminal?
2. how to resolve **"Permission denied"** for jar files?
3. Run scripts in Jenkin.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the following:

1. How to set CLASSPATH in terminal?
   A: Open new terminal you will be in your home directory example /User/pavan
   You can edit .bash_profile

   export JAVA_HOME=/user/pavan/jdk1.8.0_101

   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

   export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib

you could add your required jar paths with colon separated.

2 How to resolve "Permission deined" for jar files?

You might tried jar command use the following:
    java -jar yourtarget.jar

3. Run scripts in Jenkin.

You need to create a job in Jenkin dashboard.In the build section you give shell scripts or commands as shown below image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pavan.. I will check out.